# How can I convert following derived table query to django ORM?

Tags: django, django-orm

```
 SELECT count(user_min.user_id_id), date(user_min.date_time) from 
   ((SELECT MIN(date(date_time)) as date_time,user_id_id FROM `pied_visit` WHERE branch_id_id IN (5,6,9) GROUP BY user_id_id) user_min) 
   GROUP BY date(user_min.date_time)
```

Searched at lots of places. But couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Why don't you consider using raw SQL queries instead of converting it to ORM? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#

Comment: I can use that. But I want to learn how to convert this query to ORM.

Comment: It is very easy. Just follow the documentation for the syntax and how to operate on the results.

Comment: I checked, but didn't find anything. Can u show me?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#

Comment: I want to convert this in ORM. I know how to use it with raw sql.

Comment: You shouldn't be thinking in terms of converting queries to ORM. Instead, think about what your query *does*, and then think about how you would express that in Django.

Comment: You are true! But I am new to django. and I don't have the necessary knowledge about Django. I would be very grateful if you provide some help.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a weird SQL query. I am not sure if it is even possible to do it in one statement.

Let us start with this subquery:
`SELECT MIN(date(date_time)) as date_time,user_id_id FROM "pied_visit" WHERE branch_id_id IN (5,6,9) GROUP BY user_id_id) user_min`

As far as I know, there is no way to provide table aliases in Django, so if the alias is only important for it to function in the outer query, and if `PiedVisit` is the Django model name for the SQL table `pied_visit`, we can get it like so:

```
p = PiedVisit.objects.values('user_id_id').annotate(new_date_time=Min(TruncDate(date_time)).filter(branch_id_id__in=[5,6,9])
```

The above example only works in Django 1.10 and above, because `TruncDate` is not available in lower versions. You will have to use the `.extra()` queryset API and insert raw SQL for older versions.

Whatever the results of the earlier statement, you just process in Python using list comprehensions and collections.

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter([row['new_date_time'] for row in p])
dict(c)
```

You will end up with a `dict` whose keys are the dates, and the respective values will be the count.

Documentation on [TruncDate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.datetime.TruncDate) and [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra).